# Can individual GitHub status checks require maintainer approval to run?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm maintaining an open source project. I want to add a new check to PRs that does not automatically run until I allow it to, but I still want other checks to automatically run.

Ideally, I'd like GitHub to show this UI:

[image: GitHub UI]

but only for certain checks, and not all. Is this possible?